# How/when/where to include external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to hold my JavaScript (jQuery) functions.

I am developing in MVC/razor and therefore have a layout page.  I include my jQuery library and an external JavaScript file in here so it's available in every single page.

This is working well, but I am now becoming very aware of the fact that I am adding almost 300 lines of JS to EVERY page, where maybe half of that is used in any one of these pages.

One function is not in the external file and instead sits inside the HTML because I need to use variables set in my razor code.

I have a couple of questions around this arrangement:

- Is placing JS inside the HTML generally acceptable when variables set using razor are used? There does not appear to be a clean way of passing a variable into an external js file
- Should I split my functions down in to individual JS files and just include what is needed for each page in the site?
- If I were to split them into multiple files, how would that work with jQuery's `(document).ready` ? Do I need to use that if all the JavaScript I am including is to be used?

I'm sure this will more a matter of opinion than a black and white answer, but I want to consider all my options before moving on.  Even though it works fine as is, I can't help but feel there is a better/cleaner way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember once a user lands on your homepage and loads the javascript file it will be cached in their browser so subsequent pages will not download the Javascript again.

I would definitely keep the js separate, you could have a snippet on each page that initialise the JS that that particurlar view needs. Put something like the below in the views that need to run JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    mysite.mypage();
});
```

Then the function mysite.mypage() can be defined in the external JS file. 
300 lines isnt the end of the world, I would say its probably too early to be worryign about optimisation.

You could always look at minifying that JS file to decrease the size. A quick and easy way to do this is here:

http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

Comment: Thanks for that - all code is minified when deployed, plus I hadn't consider caching (not to mention more http requests if I used 4 external files rather than 1).

Comment: /agree. If you only have 300 lines then I would keep it all on one page. If you're worried about running all of those functions on every page then you can split them up into sections and check the page you're on then run only the functions you need for that page. I usually namespace my js and provide an init for each one and stick it in an if statement: if($('#Homepage'){MySite.Homepage.init()}

Comment: @Syon: You are not "running all of those functions on every page", you are merely including them. Also, separating every JS module in a different file makes sense for a better management of your files, but performancewise I would always put everything in one file. The user loads it once and cache will do the rest. Probably the best set up is, logically separating your JS modules in different files and using a preprocessor to concatenate and minify your javascript code.

Comment: @Amberlamps - I think you misunderstood me. If you have a js function that begins onload to do something on a specific page - like stripe rows in a table on the Data page - then you don't need the overhead of searching for that table and performing the action on the homepage. So by separating your js into smaller modules and calling them based on the page you can reduce a little overhead. Also; separating modules in diff pages makes sense if you have a ton of code, but 300 lines is hardly worthy of multiple files

Comment: @Syon: Do not separate your code into smaller modules. You will **increase** your overhead: Different javascript files will cause more HTTP requests and more files in the cache. Have a single javascript file for your whole domain. All available functions will be cached already. There is no overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever heard of require.js? http://requirejs.org/  I find it really useful.

It's a module loader so you are able to split all of your JS code into individual files and load only the ones you need on each page.

I don't know about passing a variable to an external JS file, I don't think its possible / the 'right' way.

You can make each external JS file into a function that accepts and returns parameters. Then in the page you need to use it: 
- include the file dependancy
- call the function

Thats what I do, seems like your 2nd suggestion.

for the $(document.ready) question its really up to you. You don't have to use it but its useful for some things , check out this overview: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: What is so difficult in passing variable to an external JS file. You will have to know the signature of the external functions to pass values properly. But that is the same thing for internal functions.

Comment: @Amberlamps Do you have an example of passing a variable to an external js file?  I currently have one function inside my HTML because it uses a varibale set in my MVC/razor code.

Comment: I think, that there is something, that I don´t get, because it is too simple. At the point when the document is fully loaded, any global function and variable is accessible by any other function regardless of location. If you have an external JS file the includes the function `function sayName(name) { alert(name); }`, you can call `sayName('Alan')` from anywhere.

Comment: @Amberlamps +1 for making me feel seriously dumb.

Comment: @Amberlamps - that's calling the function :) if you need to send `var name` back, you should put `return name` at the end. "passing a variable to an external js file" sounds more like doing some URL writing or something so thats what i thought  was being attempted

Comment: @Peadar: Thx, but you really don´t need to teach my the basics of how functions work :)